# JSON Unmarshalling javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:

Tags: java, json, jaxb, cxf

I am trying Unmarshall a JSON to Java Object. I have seen quite few Posts which talks about parsing XML. So i hope question is not duplicate

My Java class has below annotations

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "cpResponse")
public class CPResponse {
```

I am using **org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider** from cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers - version - 2.7.3

I get the below error

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"cpResponse")

Comment: I guess you are using Jettison, Please, post your JSON to see elements. have you receiving content-type application/json? It seems you are receiving XML

Comment: You are correct @ArK . The problem was with Jettison Library 1.3.x version. I downgraded to 1.2 and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to view the java mapper class.
For each field in json you want to map, define getter and setter in Java Mapper Class.You can read data from json to java pojo as below:
Using jackson-databind-2.0.0 api you can use below code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonMapperVO jsonMapperVO = mapper.readValue(jsonString.toString(), JsonMapperVO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably namespace issue. Could you please for the namespace to `""` ? :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "cpResponse", namespace = "")
public class CPResponse {
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but no change. I am getting same exception. Is it sufficient if i go only @ client side or should change done @ server side too ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Jettison Library 1.3.x version. I downgraded to 1.2 and the problem got resolved.

No other code changes involved.